# Different page conten when JS is disabled

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, cookies

i've got a slight problem with JS enabled detection.
not too big, because i know i'm on the right track.
but here's my deal:

when i try to set a cookie in JS (jQuery) using this code

```
$(window).load(function(){
    $.cookies.set('c_jsEnabled', 'true');
});
```

or just in plain JS using this code

```
function setCookie()
{
    document.cookie='c_jsEnabled=true';
}
<body onload="setCookie();">
```

and then try to detect it in PHP using this code

```
if($_COOKIE['c_jsEnabled'] == 'true')
{
    if(file_exists('./main.php'))
    {
        require_once ('./main.php');
    }
    echo getIndex();
}
else 
{
    if(file_exists('./noJS.php'))
    {
        require_once ('./noJS.php');
    }
    echo getIndex();
}
setcookie('c_jsEnabled', '');
```

it takes 2 page refreshes to actually get the right value into PHP.
my guess is that this bascially means that the PHP script is executed before the JS function is fired.
could this be because all codes shown above are in the same script (index.php)?

This is kind of a problem for me, because i want to prevent people from using my website when they have JS disabled.

is there a way to set the cookie before php tries to get the cookie variable?

Comment: PHP is run on the server, before the page is even sent to the client, so it would take at least 1 page refresh for PHP to read the cookie.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

PHP only sends the cookie header when content is sent to the browser. Javascript then executes after that, so you would need a second load of the page to detect the cookie.

This can trigger infinite redirection loops (especially if the user has cookies disabled), so be careful.

To disable the site to users without Javascript, consider the following.

```
<div id="noscript" style="width:100%; height:100%; z-index:999; position:absoloute; top:0px; left:0px; background-color:#CC9900; display:block">
Please Enable Javascript!</div>
<script type="text/javascript">
document.getElementById('noscript').style.display = 'none';
</script>
```

I find the `<noscript>` tag is unreliable (there was a bug in iOS causing it to only show when there was Javascript, if I remember correctly).

**A second option:**
You can have the PHP check for a cookie. If it isn't set, have it redirect (`header("Location: aaa.html");`) to a page with the Javascript to set the cookie and redirect back. (Alternatively, have the PHP output Javascript to set the cookie reload the page.) You then only have to worry about users who "spoof" the cookie, although you will also lock out users who have cookies disabled.

Comment: i think i'm going with this one, since this actually overlaps the entire page, and when i set the position to fixed instead of absolute, the div will scroll along the page, so no actual content can be viewed.

Answer (score 6):

PHP is *always* "fired" before JavaScript because PHP is processed on the server and then sends out the HTML and JavaScript for the browser to process and render. You can never expect JavaScript to execute before PHP for this reason.

In your case, use JavaScript to set the cookie and then do a redirect to refresh the page so PHP can get the cookie value and act accordingly.

Comment: ok, thanks for your quick reply.
is there another solution to this?

and i mean another solution that doesn't include
`<meta HTTP-EQUIV="REFRESH" content="0; url=http://www.yourdomain.com/index.html">`
because if some genius downloads the html page, and changes or removes the redirect code, it will simply ignore the redirection.

Comment: Well, your redirect would be in JavaScript, not a meta tag since you need to make sure your JavaScript runs first and if JavaScript is off then the cookie is never set anyway. Plus if someone is going to mess with your code you can't really stop them anyway. The best you can do is build your site to expect mischievous behavior and still work or at least throw an error.

Comment: If they have cookies disabled, they may get stuck in an infinite redirect.

Comment: Some smart logic *should* avoid that.

Answer (score 2):

You should be setting the cookie directly from the PHP file.  That way, you know that it exists, and more importantly, you have control of the cookie.  You can set it from the client, but that will always execute after the HTML has been sent to the browser, so the PHP file won't get it until the next request.

Answer (score 0):

Nope - PHP will always be called before client-side JavaScript, so with this method you'll always have to refresh the page at least once. You're better to develop your site so that non-JS users have a worse-but-still-acceptable experience, or at worst use the <noscript> HTML tag to serve alternative content to those users.

Comment: ok, i get that.
but doesn't 
`<noscript>
<meta HTTP-EQUIV="REFRESH" content="0; url=http://www.yourdomain.com/index.html">
</noscript>
cause an easy bypass for users when they change the source code of the index page?

Comment: @GabiBarrientos Yes, so what?

Answer (score 0):

You can't get a cookie in PHP that's being set by JavaScript before the page renders/executes.

You could [set the cookie using PHP](http://php.net/manual/en/function.setcookie.php), however. That will ensure it's set and available regardless of JavaScript or multiple page refreshes.